# Amazon EKS: generate/update kubeconfig via python script

Tags: kubernetes, boto3, aws-cli, amazon-eks

When using Amazon's K8s offering, the **EKS** service, at some point you need to connect the Kubernetes API and configuration to the infrastructure established within AWS. Especially we need a *kubeconfig* with proper credentials and URLs to connect to the k8s control plane provided by EKS.

The Amazon commandline tool `aws` provides a routine for this task

```
aws eks update-kubeconfig --kubeconfig /path/to/kubecfg.yaml --name <EKS-cluster-name>
```

### Question: do the same through Python/boto3

When looking at the [Boto API documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/eks.html), I seem to be unable to spot the equivalent for the above mentioned `aws` routine. Maybe I am looking at the wrong place.

- is there a ready-made function in *boto* to achieve this?
- otherwise how would you approach this directly within python (other than calling out to `aws` in a subprocess)?

Answer (score 15):

There isn't a method function to do this, but you can build the configuration file yourself like this:

```
# Set up the client
s = boto3.Session(region_name=region)
eks = s.client("eks")

# get cluster details
cluster = eks.describe_cluster(name=cluster_name)
cluster_cert = cluster["cluster"]["certificateAuthority"]["data"]
cluster_ep = cluster["cluster"]["endpoint"]

# build the cluster config hash
cluster_config = {
        "apiVersion": "v1",
        "kind": "Config",
        "clusters": [
            {
                "cluster": {
                    "server": str(cluster_ep),
                    "certificate-authority-data": str(cluster_cert)
                },
                "name": "kubernetes"
            }
        ],
        "contexts": [
            {
                "context": {
                    "cluster": "kubernetes",
                    "user": "aws"
                },
                "name": "aws"
            }
        ],
        "current-context": "aws",
        "preferences": {},
        "users": [
            {
                "name": "aws",
                "user": {
                    "exec": {
                        "apiVersion": "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1",
                        "command": "heptio-authenticator-aws",
                        "args": [
                            "token", "-i", cluster_name
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }

# Write in YAML.
config_text=yaml.dump(cluster_config, default_flow_style=False)
open(config_file, "w").write(config_text)
```

Comment: I tried this and had trouble with: `client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1`.  When I generate such a file via `aws` I get `client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1`.

Answer (score 2):

I faced same problem decided to implement it as a Python package
it can be installed via

```sh
pip install eks-token
```

and then simply do

```py
from eks_token import get_token
response = get_token(cluster_name='<value>')
```

More details and examples [here](https://pypi.org/project/eks-token/)

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in *Create kubeconfig manually* section of https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-kubeconfig.html, which is in fact referenced from the boto3 EKS docs. The manual method there is very similar to @jaxxstorm's answer except that it doesn't shown the python code you would need, however it also does not assume heptio anthenticator (it shows token and IAM authenticator approaches).

Answer (score 1):

Amazon's `aws` tool is included in the python package [awscli](https://pypi.org/project/awscli/), so one option is to add `awscli` as a python dependency and just call it from python.  The code below assumes that `kubectl` is installed (but you can remove the test if you want).

#### kubeconfig depends on `~/.aws/credentials`

One challenge here is that the kubeconfig file generated by `aws` has a users section like this:

```
users:
- name: arn:aws:eks:someregion:1234:cluster/somecluster
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
      args:
      - --region
      - someregion
      - eks
      - get-token
      - --cluster-name
      - somecluster
      command: aws
```

So if you you mount it into a container or move it to a different machine you'll get this error when you try to use it:

```
Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".
```

Based on that user section, `kubectl` is running `aws eks get-token` and it's failing because the `~/.aws` dir doesn't have the credentials that it had when the kubeconfig file was generated.

You could get around this by **also** staging the `~/.aws` dir everywhere you want to use the kubeconfig file, but I have automation that takes a lone kubeconfig file as a parameter, so I'll be modifying the user section to include the necessary secrets as [env vars](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/config-api/kubeconfig.v1/#ExecEnvVar).

Be aware that this makes it possible for whoever gets that kubeconfig file to use the secrets we've included for other things.  Whether this is a problem will depend on how much power your aws user has.

#### Assume Role

If your cluster uses RBAC, you might need to specify which role you want for your kubeconfig file.  The code below does this by first generating a separate set of creds and then using them to generate the kubeconfig file.

Role assumption has a timeout (I'm using 12 hours below), so you'll need to call the script again if you can't manage your mischief before the token times out.

#### The Code

You can generate the file like:

```
pip install awscli boto3 pyyaml sh
python mkkube.py > kubeconfig
```

...if you put the following in `mkkube.py`

```py
from pathlib import Path
from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory
from time import time

import boto3
import yaml
from sh import aws, sh

aws_access_key_id = "AKREDACTEDAT"
aws_secret_access_key = "ubREDACTEDaE"
role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::1234:role/some-role"
cluster_name = "mycluster"
region_name = "someregion"

# assume a role that has access
sts = boto3.client(
    "sts",
    aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
    aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key,
)

assumed = sts.assume_role(
    RoleArn=role_arn,
    RoleSessionName="mysession-" + str(int(time())),
    DurationSeconds=(12 * 60 * 60),  # 12 hrs
)

# these will be different than the ones you started with
credentials = assumed["Credentials"]
access_key_id = credentials["AccessKeyId"]
secret_access_key = credentials["SecretAccessKey"]
session_token = credentials["SessionToken"]


# make sure our cluster actually exists
eks = boto3.client(
    "eks",
    aws_session_token=session_token,
    aws_access_key_id=access_key_id,
    aws_secret_access_key=secret_access_key,
    region_name=region_name,
)

clusters = eks.list_clusters()["clusters"]
if cluster_name not in clusters:
    raise RuntimeError(f"configured cluster: {cluster_name} not found among {clusters}")

with TemporaryDirectory() as kube:
    kubeconfig_path = Path(kube) / "config"

    # let awscli generate the kubeconfig
    result = aws(
        "eks",
        "update-kubeconfig",
        "--name",
        cluster_name,
        _env={
            "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID": access_key_id,
            "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY": secret_access_key,
            "AWS_SESSION_TOKEN": session_token,
            "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION": region_name,
            "KUBECONFIG": str(kubeconfig_path),
        },
    )

    # read the generated file
    with open(kubeconfig_path, "r") as f:
        kubeconfig_str = f.read()
    kubeconfig = yaml.load(kubeconfig_str, Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)

    # the generated kubeconfig assumes that upon use it will have access to
    # `~/.aws/credentials`, but maybe this filesystem is ephemeral,
    # so add the creds as env vars on the aws command in the kubeconfig
    # so that even if the kubeconfig is separated from ~/.aws it is still
    # useful
    users = kubeconfig["users"]
    for i in range(len(users)):
        kubeconfig["users"][i]["user"]["exec"]["env"] = [
            {"name": "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID", "value": access_key_id},
            {"name": "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY", "value": secret_access_key},
            {"name": "AWS_SESSION_TOKEN", "value": session_token},
        ]

    # write the updates to disk
    with open(kubeconfig_path, "w") as f:
        f.write(yaml.dump(kubeconfig))

    awsclipath = str(Path(sh("-c", "which aws").stdout.decode()).parent)
    kubectlpath = str(Path(sh("-c", "which kubectl").stdout.decode()).parent)
    pathval = f"{awsclipath}:{kubectlpath}"

    # test the modified file without a ~/.aws/ dir
    # this will throw an exception if we can't talk to the cluster
    sh(
        "-c",
        "kubectl cluster-info",
        _env={
            "KUBECONFIG": str(kubeconfig_path),
            "PATH": pathval,
            "HOME": "/no/such/path",
        },
    )

print(yaml.dump(kubeconfig))
```