# How to connect to kubernetes cluster without config file in Python SDK?

Tags: python, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am making an app that will use K8S (EKS) to orchestrate the deployments on Cluster. Currently, I am developing using Minikube so its going as expected, but it uses `$HOME/.kube/config` file to load configuration. What are the other ways to connect to EKS?

Sample Code that I am using for Proof of Work:

```py
from kubernetes import client, config

# Configs can be set in Configuration class directly or using helper utility
config.load_kube_config()

v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
print("Listing pods with their IPs:")
ret = v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(watch=False)
for i in ret.items:
    print("%s\t%s\t%s" % (i.status.pod_ip, i.metadata.namespace, i.metadata.name))
```

Comment: are you trying to access one kubernetes cluster from another? or multiple kubernetes cluster from one location?

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation for "load_authentication":

> This function goes through various authentication methods in user section of kube-config and stops if it finds a valid authentication method. The order of authentication methods is:
>
> - auth-provider (gcp, azure, oidc)
> - token field (point to a token file)
> - exec provided plugin
> - username/password

_load_authentication_ - Read authentication from kube-config user section if exists.
Here is an example how to use `client.Configuration()` with [barer token to authenticate](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/6d4587e18064288d031ed9bbf5ab5b8245460b3c/examples/remote_cluster.py).

Please take a look also for [Authenticate with the Azure Management Libraries for Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/azure/python-sdk-azure-authenticate?view=azure-python)

*###* update *###*

For AWS specific env you can use [AWS SDK for Python (Boto 3)](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html) and [Create a kubeconfig for Amazon EKS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-kubeconfig.html)

There is an community example - how to setup credentials for aws into kubeconfig or build the configuration [using boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54953190/amazon-eks-generate-update-kubeconfig-via-python-script)

Hope this help.